# How to make a button in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

There is a report contains 1000s of pages of data.Is there any way to make a button on the first page of the report so that ,if click on the button it goes to the end of the pages.
Is there any expression to be written,with out writing the vb.net code?

Comment: What format are you rendering to? You could add a bookmark to your report http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239378.aspx. However, I don't think `pdf` supports this.

Comment: yes..thank you i think this leads to the answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

There is a button like that in SSRS (you can also type page number in the box and press enter):

[image]

EDIT:

You can add a bookmark at the end of your report and then make a textbox which will jump to it (textbox properties->Action->mark "go to bookmark" and select the bookmark you made. I am not sure, however, if it works well in excel.

Comment: Thanks ,i have seen this.but my question was how can i make a button inside the ssrs report.The problem with the one you have mentioned is ,it would not be shown ,when you export to a excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

Web viewer control, this button already exists.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can add a button to SSRS and export to Excel to go to last row.
You can use Excel command to go to last cell which should work.

Refer to [http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-HP010073848.aspx][1]

CTRL+G
Displays the Go To dialog box.
F5 also displays this dialog box.

Click on "Special..." button and select "Last Cell" option and click OK

Sorry .. Tried posting images for you but not enough points to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of reaching the last page or the data on the last page:

> **Sol 1.** @kyooryu has already mentioned above in his solution along with a screenshot.
>
> **Sol 2.** You can freeze the header and set the display result to show the data on a single page. This way you will not have multiple pages and you can directly hit the end button from keyboard on the report manager to reach the bottom result set. Freezing the header will help you in identifying the column names.